Is there a metric that we can use to determine if a species is more nucleophilic or more basic?
The question is rather simple and, as such, it will probably be difficult to answer:
Is there a molecular observable or a set of molecular observables that we can calculate from first principles to determine, given certain experimental conditions (solvent, temperature etc...), if the species under study are more nucleophilic or more basic?
I am looking at a theoretical line of reasoning, not empirical rules.
Input: I would think that something like Fukui Functions, or some QTAIM indicators would be good starting points but I do not have a clue on how to design a simulation and data analysis workflow that could help predict with enough accuracy if nucleophilicity overwhelms basic behaviour.
